# Can't send mail through exec in PHP

Tags: php, email, exec, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email and I have 2 scripts:

**send.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
require_once 'class.smtp.php';

$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$body             = " ";
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 4; 
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";    
$mail->Port       = 587;                
$mail->Username   = "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com";
$mail->Password   = "XXXXXXXX";           

$mail->Subject    = "TEST";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = "YYYYYYYY@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

**script.php**

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("php send.php");
?>
```

By calling directly `send.php` in browser, the email is send. Problem is when I'm calling `script.php`, then the email is not send and Im getting an error. Here are last lines from output:

```
2016-02-09 19:19:55 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, t=300, opt=array (
                                      )
2016-02-09 19:19:55 Connection: opened
2016-02-09 19:19:55 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-02-09 19:19:55 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP cc7sm606507lbd.11 - gsmtp
                                      "
2016-02-09 19:19:55 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP cc7sm606507lbd.11 - gsmtp
                                      "
2016-02-09 19:19:55 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP cc7sm606507lbd.11 - gsmtp
2016-02-09 19:19:55 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO raspberrypi
....
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in /var/www/html/class.smtp.php on line 325
2016-02-09 19:19:55 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2016-02-09 19:19:56 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
2016-02-09 19:19:56 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "�F"
2016-02-09 19:19:56 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "�F"
2016-02-09 19:19:56 SERVER -> CLIENT: �F
2016-02-09 19:19:56 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: �F
2016-02-09 19:19:56 Connection: closed
2016-02-09 19:19:56 SMTP connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

What can be causing this issue? Im using PHP7

Comment: are you just trying to run it in the background and nothing else?

Comment: Yes I want to run it in background and I know that I can do it this way: shell_exec("nohup php send.php"). But now I'm getting this error. The problem started to began when I upgraded php5 to php7. Maybe this is important information

Comment: what is your system and how did you install php7? I suspect via a simple ./configure? Run `phpinfo()` and see if OpenSSL is enabled. If not, reinstall PHP 7 with `--with-openssl` flag

Comment: I checked `phpinfo()` and there is `--with-openssl` flag in Configure Command section. Also OpenSSL support is set to `enabled`. I compiled php7 myself with ./configure. It is possible that I did something wrong. The system is Raspbian on Raspberry

Comment: Okay, try `$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";` instead of `tls`. If this doesn't work, it's could be an extensive server issue that I'm afraid I can't solve telepathically

Comment: I tried with `ssl` and port `465`. Also by calling direct `send.php` - the mail is sent. By calling `script.php` now I'm getting different error: `SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?` I think I will just try to recompile php and install again. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Use `tls` on 587. It looks like you've based your code on an obsolete example - use the ones provided with PHPMailer. If you load the autoloader, you don't need to load the other classes.

Comment: @Synchro You have right. I actually don't need any other classes, but I have checked and this does not change anything ;)